# Classic Ajax being canceled during an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
    function submitLogin(){
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var testlabel = document.getElementById('testlabel').value;
        var postStr = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&testlabel=" + testlabel;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('mainPage').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;//ATTENTION1
            } else {
                document.getElementById('mainPage').innerHTML = "Logining......";//ATTENTION2
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "loginto.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(postStr);

}
```

These are my codes.
If I change the "mainPage" into something else in the //ATTENTION2, the page will auto send a "GET" method, but if I still use the "mainPage" in there, there will be no problem.

However, if I change the "mainPage" into something else in the //ATTENTION1, there will have no problem with the post method, the response things can be shown in the  correctly.

So, is there any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What does "something else" mean ? You need to have an id of an element in your page, where the content from the ajax response will be rendered.

For example, if you have a

```
<div id="myID"></div>
```

somewhere in the page, and change 'mainPage' in //ATTENTION1 to 'myID', then the response from the ajax request will be placed in that div.

The change you make in //ATTENTION2 is for intermediary states because it is on "else", so will not impact what happens when the ajax request is complete.